# Show that the series is convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_n=(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and $n\geq 1$
I check first $n\to \infty$ then $\lim_{n\to \infty}=(1+\frac{1}{\infty})^\infty$
$=(1+0)^\infty=1^\infty$
I don't find the next step.Help me

Comment: It is well known that this sequence converges to $e$.  This is a perfect example of why you can *not* just evaluate the limit at different points of the expression separately.  $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left(f(x)^{g(x)}\right)$ is in general not equal to $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\left((\lim\limits_{y\to\infty}f(y))^{g(x)}\right)$

Comment: Which series are you speaking of? As to the $(a_n)$ *sequence*, it is a  standard result that  its limit is *Euler's number* $\mathrm e$.

Comment: If all you wish to do is prove convergence, you can prove the following two things: It is a monotonic increasing sequence, it is bounded above (for example, by $3$).  These two together will by the dominated convergence theorem imply the convergence of the sequence.  To prove that it specifically converges to $e$, this will depend on which specific definition of $e$ you are using and will utilize the properties of $e$.

Comment: I know the result equals $e$ but i don't show.How can I show?